# docker-compose and willfarrell/autoheal not restarting container with exit 2

Tags: docker, docker-compose

docker-compose is not restarting my container even if it is listed with an exit code 2 is `docker-compose ps`.

```
      Name                     Command                  State         Ports  
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
app_autoheal_1      /docker-entrypoint autoheal      Up (healthy)                              
seafile             /sbin/my_init -- /scripts/ ...   Exit 2
```

It is defined in the `docker-compose.yaml` with `restart: always`.

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  autoheal:
    restart: always
    image: willfarrell/autoheal
    environment:
      - AUTOHEAL_CONTAINER_LABEL=all
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
  seafile:
    image: seafileltd/seafile-mc:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: seafile
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "test $$(curl -k https://localhost/api2/ping/) = '\"pong\"'"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 30s
```

In which cases can this happen?

Comment: Have you managed to fix the issue. I am looking for the same setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A container exit value of 2 is reserved by Docker. A container should `exit 1` to correctly trigger a health check.

> The command’s exit status indicates the health status of the
> container. The possible values are:
>
> - 0: success - the container is healthy and ready for us
> - 1: unhealthy - the container is not working correctly
> - 2: reserved - do not use this exit code

Source: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck

Comment: So to force it exits with status 1, make sure to get your healthcheck test command like the following: curl -f http://localhost/ || exit 1